# NodeJS: How do I perform an action after multiple asynchronous functions have completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Beginner here. I'm starting to realize that the way I'm using asynchronous functions may not be fully taking advantage of there asynchronous nature.

I do stuff like this:

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data){
  fs.readAnotherFile(anotherFile, function(err, data){
      doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded();
    });
  })
})
```

But if I'm waiting for one thing to be done before starting the other, isn't that kind of defeating the purpose of it being asynchronous?

So how would I go about doing something like this?:

```
fs.readfile(file, function(err, data){
  doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded();
});

fs.readAnotherFile(anotherFile, function(err, data){
  doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded();
});
```

Where the function in the callback isn't called until after both have loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises. Something like:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var read = Promise.denodeify(fs.readFile);

var p1 = read(file);
var p2 = read(anotherFile);
Promise.all([p1, p2])
.then(function(res) { doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded(); });
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise

Answer (score 3):

Depending on our requirements, we may need to wait for one operation to complete before we can start another operation.

But in your case, if the two operations are not related to each other, and you want to perform some action after both of them are complete, then check the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.

Using that, you can write:

```
async.each(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'], function (filename, cb) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        console.log("Reading " + filename + " complete!");
        // do something with data
        console.log(data);
        cb(null);
    });
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Reading both files is complete");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
fs.readfile(file, function(err, data){
if(i==1) doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded();
else i++
});

fs.readAnotherFile(anotherFile, function(err, data){
if(i==1) doThisAfterBothHaveLoaded(); 
else i++;
});
```

Comment: That won't work as you're doing the increment after the test, so when the first one completes `i==0` and then you increment it. When the second completes `i==1` and then you increment it to 2 but never check it again.